# Will US ps4 power cord work in 220v?

Tags: ps4

I just got a ps4 from US. The ps4 110-240v however i am not sure about the power cord given with it can work in 220v.
Will the power cord work in Pakistan or not?
Pls help me, thanks.

Comment: We don't even know where you are.  How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: My bad, i live in Pakistan

Comment: If it gives a range for 110-240, then 220v is within that range and should work safely. Have you tried plugging it into the wall?

Comment: I haven't, i am afraid that it might blow up.

Comment: If the power supply says 110v - 240v, then it will do that.  These are international standards and the US are pretty tough on labels that are accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The power cord will work, but you will need to use the appropriate adapter to plug it into the wall.

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country